# Multi window feature in android

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, multi-window

Currently only sumsung is providing multi window feature. Why others vendors can't.?

Is there any hardware dependency.?

If I want to write multi window feature for my goggle nexus how can I start.?
Any tutorial or link from where I can start.

Comment: LG has it too... 'dual window' feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will check out at [SAMSUNG Developers](http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile-sdk) packages are of two types :

Type 1 : Implemented in the Android API.

Type 2 : Implemented in the Android Framework.

You can see there MultiWindow is of package Type 2. This means for MultiWindow support SAMSUNG have heavily modified the Android Framework. So until and unless there is no vendor support you can not develope applications using MultiWindow feature for that vendor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, by looking at the link can i say multi window feature is independent of hardware.? its only requires modification in android framework.

Comment: I am not sure but yes the feature should be independent of hardware as the same hardware used by SAMSUNG is used by many other vendors. Though it may require latest hardware and may not possible to Implement in old hardware.